# How we can hide the scrollbar of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

Am wondering how we can hide the scrollbar of a div element ?

Using the code in the example below, the central div has a vertical scrollbar when we 'll write lot of text into it :

```
<html>
 <body style="height:100%; width:100%">
    <div id="header" style="position:absolute; background-color: red; top:0px; left:0px; height:200px; right:0px;overflow:hidden;"> 
    </div> 
    <div id="content" style="position:absolute; background-color: silver; top:200px; bottom:200px; left:0px; right:0px; overflow:auto; "> 

   <p>Loremenrfei hwofhwefhewufwehfuwefwe fwefhw fwhe ufhhew fweofwehfo ewhohweweofwefoiweh w we fwe fweufweufhweuwheufwefuwefhwe fuhewfuiew fuwefwe wuiewuiwehufwefiuwehfi ewfw ew ifhweuifwei uwuweufheuiwhfiu fhwef hwf wwe wehfwewfweffwehfewh we  fiwei  fugha fuha FUHA fuHa Hafu fuh</p>

        <ul>
            <li>Traalalsalsasakskjasaslka asajsa sajsa jsasja</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>END</li>
        </ul>

    </div> 
    <div id="footer" style="position:absolute; background-color: green; bottom:0px; height:200px; left:0px; right:0px; overflow:hidden;"> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My question so, is how we can hide the vertical scrollbar of the central div but to keep scrooling ..?

Comment: what you mean by ` keep scrooling ..?` ?

Comment: Hi Tushar Gupta, i mean that par example, if i change overflow:auto; to overflow:hidden; the scrollbar is not visible anymore but then the div is not scrolling anymore ! So how we can keep scrolling this div ?

Comment: Try Set `width` in 2nd div and remove `overflow: auto; `

Comment: the problem is teh height not the widthm removing overflow: auto; and setting width doses nothing... may i did not understand you well ?

Comment: Did you try the answer posted below .

Comment: yes but does not solve the problem, it makes it worse..

Comment: Question, what exactly do you mean by 'hide verticall scrollbar but keep scrolling'?

Comment: Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/avgrho/T883j/

Comment: blurfus, i mean the user to be able to scrool the text that is into that div !

Comment: you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/n4tn6/

Comment: YES blurfus exactly ! Like this one i want to make it .

Comment: A scrollable div with no scroll bar will be very confusing. It may be what you are trying to do but think of the user experience

Comment: lbu, actually i wanted to do something like this one here : http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/AnimatedHeader/ ...but anyway, thats was my inspiration ! Just i didnt want to make it in HTML5 but in XHTML .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, You need to add `position: absolute` to the header and footer and slide the content under them by using `index:-10`.  See this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n4tn6/)

**UPDATE:** adding relevant code for reference (removed all inline styling as its not inline with best-practices)

```
.body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#footer, #header, #content {
    display:block;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#footer {
    bottom: 0;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
#header {
    color: white;
    top: 0;
    background-color: black;
}
#content {
    top: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: -10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your point right, you want the div **not  to have a scrollbar**, but **still scroll with the mouse wheel or PgDn/PgUp and so on**. Right?

I don't have the code right now (you can call me a bad answerer for that; however it's late and if you want it I can edit this answer in a day or two to give you the proper code), but the idea is as follows:

- Add JavaScript event listeners for the mouse wheel and the key press (`mousewheel DOMMouseScroll` and `keydown`);
- Use the mouse wheel event object's `delta` for getting the scroll direction and scrolling the div up (negative) or down (positive);
- Capture the key codes for down arrow, up arrow, PgDn, PgUp and spacebar (I can at least tell you spacebar is `32`) and make them scroll the div up or down by an index.

Helpful links: [window.scrollTo()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp), [HTML5 and JavaScript mouse wheel](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/), [JavaScript key codes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

I'd also recommend using jQuery. It would make such a task much easier, and many tasks of this kind much lighter in your apps overall.

Please bear with the lack of code, if you still need some examples I'll edit this tomorrow night. Best of luck!